# How ibase_restore working with php?

Tags: php, firebird

I'm trying to restore a Firebird database using ibase_restore, and I get nothing. I found no documentation on the internet. I need help!

This is the code I used, with the gbak command from console I have restored it perfectly.

```
$servidor = 'localhost';
$usuario = 'sysdba';
$password = '*******';

if (($service = ibase_service_attach($servidor, $usuario, $password)) !== FALSE) {
   $result = ibase_restore($service, '/folder/BACKUP.FBK',
                  $servidor.':/folder/RESTORE.FDB');

   var_dump($result);

   ibase_service_detach($service);
}
```

Comment: What exactly are the errors? What does ibase_service_attach / ibase_restore return?

Comment: var_dump of ibase_service_attach resource(48, interbase service manager handle)
var_dump of ibase_restore boolean true