# Restore Firebird database with PHP

Tags: php, firebird

I did a backup

```
<?PHP

$host    = 'LUIS-PC/3051';
$file     = 'C:\sge\BANCO.FDB';
$username = 'SYSDBA';
$password = 'masterkey';

$resource_service_handle = ibase_service_attach ($host,$username,$password);
ibase_backup($resource_service_handle,$file,'C:\sge\bd.fbk');
ibase_service_detach ($resource_service_handle);
```

but the restore didn't work

```
$resource_service_handle = ibase_service_attach ($host,$username,$password);
ibase_restore($resource_service_handle, 'C:\sge\bd.fbk', 'C:\sge\abcde.fdb');
ibase_service_detach ($resource_service_handle);
```

There is no error message

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467816/how-ibase-restore-working-with-php.

Comment: @renéhoffmann - It didn't work